# If there are no gravity under the general theory of relativity, how can we be attracted to massive objects (from the side)?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity, spacetime, curvature

Watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRr1kaXKBsU), it is explained that there are no force of gravity under the general theory of relativity, but a force made by objects moving through spacetime.

The example made in this video to try to help understanding the idea is someone (the author of the video) being on a spaceship in deep space, and having is spaceship accelerating.

In that case, if you were to be on top of that ship, you would also feel that acceleration (or "attraction" if we were to compare it with a Newtonian thinking). BUT, if you were to be on the opposite part of the ship (where the rocket burns), you would see the ship get away from you (we can ignore the part where you burn ;) ).

I understand that the theory suggested here works regardless of where you stand, at the top or under the spaceship, and there were a lot of questions in regard to "what would happens to people living at the opposite of earth".

The author of the video, Veritasium, made an explanation here as a comment, which I'm pasting here:

> Either watch again from 8:28 or read what I've written below...
>
> Spacetime is curved - it curves the opposite direction on the other
> side of the Earth.
>
> Neither us on this side of the Earth nor they on the other side are
> changing our spacial coordinates - we're not moving up, they're not
> moving down - Earth isn't flying into one of us.
>
> BUT we both ARE accelerating. In curved spacetime you have to
> accelerate just to remain stationary.
>
> The traditional definition of acceleration is something changing its
> velocity.
>
> In general relativity you have to embrace a new definition of
> acceleration: it means deviating from a geodesic - not going on a
> straight line path through spacetime. Near the Earth a geodesic is a
> parabola so unless you're moving in a parabolic arc (like on a zero-g
> plane) you are accelerating.
>
> This definition is the same as the old one  so if you're accelerating
> in deep space then your velocity is changing.
>
> *BUT*... if you are near a large mass you are in curved spacetime, now acceleration  your velocity is changing. You can stay stationary
> relative to Earth's surface and still be accelerating. This is because
> your acceleration should be measured not relative to the Earth's
> surface but relative to free-falling objects - they are inertial
> observers.
>
> Imagine this - I'm in deep space and I make horizontal rows and rows
> of stationary golf balls. Then I hop in my rocket and accelerate up
> through them. Just think about what that looks like. Now my rocket is
> back on Earth just sitting there. I freeze time for a sec and make
> horizontal rows and rows of golf balls up into the atmosphere. Now
> unfreeze time. What do you see? If you just look at the golf balls and
> the rocket ship it looks the same as the situation in space where the
> golf balls were stationary and the rocket was accelerating. Einstein's
> point was the golf balls have the better claim as the "stationary"
> thing since their experience is just like the golf balls in deep space
>
> - no forces experienced. The rocket on Earth is just like the rocket in space. It feels a force and hence an acceleration.

But still, I'm having a hard time understanding this. Even worse is when I forget about being on top or under, where opposite force applies when you think just in terms of movement (the space ship do move under a straight line).

What I'm having a hard time to wrap my head around, is if we replace the ship with a massive object, such as the Sun. It still moves through spacetime, but it doesn't move in a straight line, because again, on top you would be on it's path, and under, you would see it get away.

My real question is:

**But what happens when you come from the side ?!** That's my full confusion here. It has been proven that a massive objects "attracts" you regardless of where you come. I'm interested and intrigued about the theory of "no attraction but object moving through spacetime" but in the given video, I can't see how I would be attracted to a Sun moving in a straight line.

Can you explain this to me, like I'm 5 maybe?

Comment: I think your difficulty is owing to trying to follow an unclear presentation. I recommend you seek out clearer presentations. Anything by A. Einstein or by R. Feynman (among others) would be clearer.

Comment: Nothing is “moving through spacetime”. Spacetime is static. Things move through space over time.

Comment: A geodesic is not “a straight line path through spacetime”, but the shortest path through spacetime. These concepts are the same in the Euclidean geometry, but totally different in the hyperbolic Lorentzian geometry of spacetime.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification. I think I lack the knowledge to better grasp the idea.